# Which method to use similar ScrollChanged but on WP8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to use the  event ScrollChanged of the ScrollViewer control, but it is only available on Windows 8. Windows Phone 8 RT which method I can use that is equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime apps can use the same ScrollViewer events as Windows Store 8.1 apps: [ViewChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged.aspx) and [ViewChanging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanging.aspx).

Windows Phone Silverlight's ScrollViewer doesn't have a direct analog to this event. If I recall correctly, the ScrollChanged event is specific to WPF's ScrollViewer.